# Url formats for my website

Tags: seo

I have a doubt with my website which is related to movies.

I am creating my website in two versions for all the Industries like XYZ/ Tollywood / movie-news (For english version).

xyz/telugu-movie-news (telugu version)

Similar type for Bollywood and Kollywood too.. But my doubt is there are some other languages like Bhojpuri, bengali, Punjabi, oriya and many more. For them there is no specific industry so can I give urls like xyz/bengali/movie-news(English version) and xyz/bengali/bengali-movie-news (bengali language version).....

Is that correct?? Would it be useful for SEO or any problem for SEO??? Please help me out...

Comment: See also this question on Serverfault - https://serverfault.com/questions/52946/ - "Website strategy for having a single site work for multiple countries?"

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems in your question is that none of your examples are valid domain names, unless xyz and XYZ stand for domain-name.com or something.

There are 2 main ways to handle your situation, both having been proven to be SEO friendly. Let's assume a basic domain name such as 'movie-news.com'. The 2-letter code [found here](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) can either be used as a subdomain or as a prefix to the uri. Examples for Bengali:

- http://movie-news.com   << default
  language such as English or any other
  of your choice
- http://bn.movie-news.com   << Bengali, indicated in the subdomain
- http://movie-news.com/bn   << Bengali again, on the same domain (my preferred version)

Then all pages can be added onto that.

- http://movie-news.com/my-cool-page
- http://bn.movie-news.com/my-cool-page
- http://movie-news.com/bn/my-cool-page

Answer (score 0):

It s always recommended that you use descriptive URL's

For Example:

```
http://www.exampe.com/sample-page
http://www.example.com/sample-keyword-page
```

Also make sure that you separate URL's with "-" but **no underscore** "_", because words separated with *underscores* is treated as one word in search engines, where as if you separate them with "-" *hyphens*, they are treated as single words, and you can choose variations between them.